# How to make ubuntu installed on other HDD password protected on windows 7?

Tags: hard-drive

OK so heres my question:
I have 2 HDD one with windows 7 one with ubuntu 11.10.I want the HDD accesible from ubuntu and not on windows meaning that i want it so that nobody can access the file via windows nor format the drive unless there is the input of a password.THXS

Answer (score 0):

You can use encryption to protect the data on the Ubuntu drive, either full disk, [home dir](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EncryptedHome) or just [one directory](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EncryptedPrivateDirectory).

There is no way to avoid that the disk can be formatted, short of disabling it in the BIOS or similar tricks.